# Как понять данное предложение

Tags: запятые, смысл, анализ-текста

> К пункту "а" относятся: заболевания сердца, том числе комбинированные
>   или сочетанные приобретенные пороки с сердечной недостаточностью III
>   или IV ФК по классификации NYHA;
>
> изолированные аортальные пороки сердца при наличии сердечной
>   недостаточности II - IV ФК по классификации NYHA; изолированный стеноз
>   левого атриовентрикулярного отверстия вне зависимости от
>   функционального класса сердечной недостаточности;
>
> дилатационная и рестриктивная кардиомиопатия, гипертрофическая
>   кардиомиопатия с обструкцией выносящего тракта левого желудочка;
>
> Функциональная (вагусная) AV-блокада I степени (нормализация
>   AV-проводимости возникает при физической нагрузке или после
>   внутривенного введения 0,5 - 1,0 мг атропина сульфата), неполная
>   блокада правой ножки пучка Гиса, неспецифические внутрижелудочковые
>   блокады, единичные желудочковые и наджелудочковые экстрасистолы не
>   являются основанием для применения настоящей статьи, не препятствуют
>   прохождению службы, поступлению в образовательные учреждения.

В данном предложении, неполная блокада правой ножки пучка Гиса к чему относится ? 
Не препятствует прохождению службы, или относится к пункту а)  ?

Comment: Прежде всего советую проверить источник информации. У меня по запросу "К пункту "а" относятся" гуглится более полный и осмысленный текст, в котором между последними двумя Вашими абзацами есть ещё несколько предложений. Тот текст у меня не вызывает никаких сомнений.

Answer (score 2):

> В данном предложении, неполная блокада правой ножки пучка Гиса к чему
>   относится ? Не препятствует прохождению службы, или относится к пункту
>   а) ?

Здесь, вероятно, имеется в виду, что не препятствует прохождению службы. 
В предыдущем абзаце точка с запятой судя по всему - ошибочна, после слова "желудочка" там должна быть точка.

Других объяснений у меня нет.

Но вообще-то этот текст околоюридической направленности, здесь таких специалистов нет. а юристы никаких доводов не признают, кроме собственных. Поэтому в случае принципиальной необходимости придется делать лингвистическую экспертизу.

На всякий случай даю адрес, где могут помочь. Но - дорого.
http://rusexpert.ru/